# Approach to asynchronous web programming ( Working on Google Image Labeler site look like )

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, comet

I want to create a website like [Google Image Labeler](http://images.google.com/imagelabeler/), in which people can tag images.
but this is my first serious web programming project and my problem is that I don't know what are requirements for doing this job.

In this site what I have to do is First : pair people randomly and second : I need to send each session information to server asynchronously ( not only client to server [ AJAX ], but also server to client [ by using comet I guess ] )
I have Python and PHP programming experience and also I'm familiar with AJAX and Javascript. 
In my 2, 3 days journy(!) for finding suitable tools to doing this project I encountered to lot of stuffs : websocket, jquery, comet, socke.io, nod.js and a lot more which just made me so confused.

in fact I'm looking for a good reference helps me on where to start and what to do. ( or you can think of it as : what is best approach for starting asnyc web programming )
thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a lots of trying I got here :

to start async web programming , first of all you need to get familiar with AJAX, it's not that hard . you can earn all you need from w3schools.

after that the best choice you have is jquery . there is lots of incredible things you can do with it . one of it's capabilities is that you can send and receive data using ajax without reloading the page . To get familiar with jquery live page manipulation you can check [How to Create A Simple Web-based Chat Application](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/).
Also you can use some of html 5 technologies such as SSE ( server sent events [ more convenient ] one directional connection ) or websockets ( bidirectional connection, useful for web game programming )
In order to pair people you can use Mysql database as a medium to hold each new user's information and after that pair them using an unique id , such as session id . obviously you can use files as a medium too .

That's almost all you need to create a live updating web site , but if you want to do it much more professionally and in the server side, you can look at node.js ( server side javascript, an event oriented programming ) or twisted ( a python frame work ).

This is all I learned in my way .
Sorry for unwanted mistakes .